# Why is “Tuesday” placed in the sentence without being preceded by the preposition “on”?

Tags: prepositions

THE SOURCE: Wall Street Journal

> In a village on their heavily militarized border, North and South Korean officials opened talks **Tuesday**, ostensibly over...

I think the preposition “on” should come before?

Comment: The day of the week can be used absolutely in the singular to mean "on the  Tuesday of the current or coming week" as context requires.  *He's having his wisdom teeth out Tuesday. He has his wisdom teeth out Tuesday. He had his wisdom teeth out Tuesday.  He was having his wisdom teeth out Tuesday.*

Answer (score 2):

Adjunct that expresses temporal location can be realised by Noun Phrases (NP), though these NPs are very limited in number. The day of the week is one such NP that can be used as a temporal Adjunct like the way ***Tuesday*** is used in OP's quoted sentence.

The quoted sentence is correct. Though inserting ***"on"*** before ***Tuesday*** there doesn't make it ungrammatical by any means. I personally prefer the version with "on", might be because of the variation of English I am accustomed to.

A note from Fowler's Modern English Usage:

> The natural use shown in *He normally eats fish on Fridays* varies occas. with the type *He normally eats fish Fridays*, i.e. with omission of "on", esp. in AmE. Only an American, I think, would say *I saw you Friday* (cf. *Noriega ... said Monday the U.S. Southern Command in Panama ... threatens the Central American nation* —USA Today, 1988), but there is a great deal of variation in such contexts in rapid speech.